# Show local notification on particular days

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, nsdatecomponents

Today's date is 2013-04-17 10:39:00 +0000. Now  i am selecting weekdays from table to set schedule(alarm) of that day. I want to show local notification alert on selected days forever. But i am getting problems.

Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)setDays{
NSDate *date1=[df dateFromString:time123];  //2013-04-17 10:39:00 +0000
 NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
            NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date1];
             NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) 
             fromDate:date1];
            [components setHour:[timeComponents hour]]; 
            [components setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
            [components setSecond:0];


            NSString *su=@"false";
            NSString *mo=@"false";
            NSString *tu=@"false";
            NSString *we=@"false";
            NSString *th=@"false";
            NSString *fr=@"false";
            NSString *sa=@"false";
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                su=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:1];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date1 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"1"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                mo=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:2];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date2 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"2"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:2] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                tu=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:3];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date3 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"3"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:3] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                we=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:4];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date4 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"4"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:4] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                th=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:5];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date5 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"5"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:5] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                fr=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:6];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date6 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"6"];
            }
            if ([[selectedDays objectAtIndex:6] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                sa=@"true";
                [components setWeekday:7];
                NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
                NSLog(@"date7 %@",itemDate);
                [appDelegate scheduleNotification:@"hi shiv" repeatDaily:YES fireDate:itemDate forKey:@"7"];
            }
}
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
-(UILocalNotification * )scheduleNotification:(NSString *)remainderText repeatDaily:(BOOL )isRepeat fireDate:(NSDate *)fireDate forKey:(NSString*)key{

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if (cls != nil) {
        NSLog(@"in set local notification");
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate = fireDate;

        if (isRepeat == FALSE) {

            notif.repeatInterval = 0;

        } else {
            notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
            notif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
        }

        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notif.alertBody = remainderText;
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        notif.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"shiv",key, nil];

                                   [app scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
                                   NSLog(@"Added an event with ");
                                         return notif;


    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Alerts are not showing on selected days. They are showing on today's weekday only.(like all Wednesday of the month)